# How was 手伝わなあかん conjugated?

Tags: conjugations, kansai-ben

I was wondering how 手伝わなあかん was conjugated.
I know that it consists of the words 手伝う and あかん but I don't know why the い was dropped. Is it slang?

Answer (score 3):

This な is a Kansai-ben contracted version of [ねば](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/3061/5010), which is an (archaic/literary) negative-hypothetical verb ending (≒"if not").

> #### [近畿方言#否定](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E8%BF%91%E7%95%BF%E6%96%B9%E8%A8%80#%E5%90%A6%E5%AE%9A)
>
> 仮定形は「ね」であるが、後続の助詞「ば」と融合して「な」や「ん」となる（例：行かねばあかん→行かなあかん、行かねばならん→行かなならん・行かんならん）。

- **手伝う**: to help/assist
- **手伝わぬ**: not to help (archaic negative form)
- **手伝わねば**: if not help (archaic negative-hypothetical form)
- **手伝わな**: if not help (Kansai-ben contraction of 手伝わねば)

So your sentence is 手伝わねばならない or 手伝わないといけない in standard Japanese.

---

- あかん is originally 明かぬ, but it means "sucks" or "is bad" in Kansai-ben. See [this question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/25998/5010).
- Just like ねば/ないと in standard Japanese, な in Kansai-ben can mean "must" on its own.

  > もう行かないと。= もう行かねば。= もう行かな。= It's time to go.
- ねば can contract also to にゃ or にゃあ in many dialects in middle/western Japan.

  > 手伝わなにゃならん。 = 手伝わないといけない。 = I must help them.